# Automate the sync between Publisher (SQL Server 2019) and Subscriber (SQL Server 2019 Express)

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I already created the Publication and Subscription on SQL Server 2019 Standard (OS 2019) and SQL Server 2019 Express edition (Windows 10). How can I automatically do the auto sync if there are changes on both databases? I am using merge replication. Last time I am using Data Sync Center on Windows 7 but on Windows 10 How can I do this?

Hoping that someone could give me a helpful solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To initiate a sync from the client you'll need to use [RMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/concepts/replication-management-objects-concepts?view=sql-server-ver16).  Here's an old-but-still-valid [doc with sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms147890(v=sql.90)).  EG for a Merge Pull Subscription:

```
// Define server, publication, and database names.
String subscriberName = subscriberInstance;
String publisherName = publisherInstance;
String publicationName = "AdvWorksSalesOrdersMerge";
String publicationDbName = "AdventureWorks";
String subscriptionDbName = "AdventureWorksReplica";

// Create a connection to the Subscriber.
ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(subscriberName);

MergePullSubscription subscription;

try
{
    // Connect to the Subscriber.
    conn.Connect();

    // Define subscription properties.
    subscription = new MergePullSubscription();
    subscription.ConnectionContext = conn;
    subscription.DatabaseName = subscriptionDbName;
    subscription.PublisherName = publisherName;
    subscription.PublicationDBName = publicationDbName;
    subscription.PublicationName = publicationName;

    // If the pull subscription and the job exists, start the agent job.
    if (subscription.LoadProperties() && subscription.AgentJobId != null)
    {
        subscription.SynchronizeWithJob();
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something here if the subscription does not exist.
        throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(
            "A subscription to '{0}' does not exists on {1}",
            publicationName, subscriberName));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Do appropriate error handling here.
    throw new ApplicationException("The subscription could not be synchronized.", ex);
}
finally
{
    conn.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Browne- How can I implement the script above? Is there anything like a batch file sample that I could run and put on a task scheduler?

Comment: You can convert that to powershell.

Comment: Browne- Can I cut and paste the script that you gave me or how can I convert this to PowerShell equivalent. Thank you very much.